# Spring boot using pathvariable to get hold of an id from url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm struggling with attaining an id from the url to use as a parameter in my read() method. 
I read and have seen dusin of examples of using @PathVariable and I can't see why this should not work.

This is my controller class.

```
@GetMapping("details/{id}")
    public String read(@PathVariable int employeeId, Model model)
    {

        model.addAttribute("students_data", studentsRepo.read(employeeId));

        //the line underneath will work using as an example the int 2 in the parameter. But I want the int coming from the url.
        //model.addAttribute("students_data", studentsRepo.read(2));

        return "details";
    }
```

I get the error on the details page:

```
Fri Jan 03 12:13:44 CET 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Example of how the url could look is:

```
http://localhost:8080/details?id=2
```

Comment: URL is wrong it should be http://localhost:8080/details/2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL `http://localhost:8080/details?id=2` that you have shared contain @RequestParam and not @PathVariable

If you want to use @RequestParam then your API signature should be

```
    @GetMapping("details/")
    public String read(@RequestParam("id") int employeeId, Model model)
    {
       "details";
    }
```

If you want to use @PathVariable then your API should be

```
    @GetMapping("details/{id}")
    public String read(@PathVariable("id") int employeeId, Model model)
    {
       "details";
    }
```

Please check the difference between the two
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/10/differences-between-requestparam-and-pathvariable-annotations-spring-mvc.html

Answer (score 4):

You are using PathVariable. Therefore the URL would be:

```
http://localhost:8080/details/2
```

If you want your URL http://localhost:8080/details?id=2 then you have to use QueryParameter

```
@GetMapping("details")
public String read(@RequestParameter int id, Model model)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `@PathVariable("id") or @PathVariable int id` instead of `employeeId`

```
public String read(@PathVariable("id") int employeeId, Model model)
```

URL: http://localhost:8080/details/10

Answer (score 2):

Add the name of the variable from the path pattern.

```
@PathVariable("id")
```

Add call it with

```
http://localhost:8080/details/2
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to map the `id` to the `PathVariable` if you are using a different variable name,

```
@GetMapping("details/{id}")
public String read(@PathVariable("id") int employeeId, Model model)
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use to check the url if "id" is coming on url by using method `isPresent()`